# Time format of database field, help needed

Tags: laravel, eloquent, mutators

Time is stored in my database as H:i:s format for a timefield.
When I query I want time returned as hours:minutes without the seconds part.

I tried to set the "protected $dateFormat " setting using a Mutator. Can anyone show an example of the dateFormat setting needed?   The database must remain hour:minute:seconds time settings, only the retrieved value needs to be changed for display.

protected $dateFormat = 'Y-m-d H:i:s';  // ?

Comment: Please visit the laravel documentation here  -- https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-mutators#date-mutators .Try and let us know what's happening if not working properly

Comment: true, but I found the documentation not detailed enough to help me out. But I found the right solution now. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can make it with getters function in your model
like this:

```
public function getTimeAttribute($time){
   return date('h:i',strtotime($time))
 }
```

`Time` in function name should be your column name in upper case

Comment: Thanks, but column name in CamelCase loosing the underscore worked.

Comment: what is your column name

Comment: See my example for time_match column in next post

Answer (score 1):

One way to solve it is to treat dates as Carbon instances. The format to save on database will be auto-converted and you should use in any format.

```
protected $dates = [
    'field_name'
];
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-mutators#date-mutators

Answer (score 1):

```
// converting db column name time_match into the function as getTimeMatchAttribute worked for me. 

public function getTimeMatchAttribute($value){
        return date('H:i',strtotime($value));
    }
```